# Sanitize Parameters in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a search function that searches a list of items. My search returns results from a simple `GET` request. On the page, I would like to display to the user their query. In my controller I can retrieve their query like this:

```
def search
    @query = params[:query]
end
```

In my view, if I simply place `<%= @query %>` in the HTML this would possibly create a XSS vulnerability. How can I sanitize this parameter for use in a view?

Comment: Will it? Did you try it? AFAIK strings have been escaped by default for a decade now, unless you're stuck in a Rails 2 app. (Could be wrong, even if I am, this has been well-documented for quite some time, e.g., https://cultivatehq.com/posts/rails-3-html-escaping .)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

```
<%= sanitize(@query) %>
```